# PHP submit form without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When the user submits the form, the result should be displayed without page refreshing. The PHP script is also in the same HTML page.

What is wrong withe `$.post` jQuery?

```html
<!--
 Submit form without refreshing
-->

<html>

<head>
  <title>My first PHP page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function(event) {
        var myname = $("#name").val();
        var myage = $("#age").val();
        $.post(
          "23.php", $("#testform").serialize()
        );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="testform">
    <!-- $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] array -->
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Age:
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) { // was the form submitted?
        echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to prevent the default form action with `event.preventDefault();`  https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @Kasuni see my updated answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event.preventDefault in your javascript

```
       $("#btn").click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          var myname = $("#name").val();
          var myage = $("#age").val();

            $.post( 
              "23.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize()
           );

        });
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I added the event.preventDefault(); but still the page loads refreshing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need e.preventDefault. Also, I think these var myname and myage variables are unnecessary since you're serializing the entire form in $.post.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            "23.php", $("#testform").serialize()
        );
     });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: thanks lot for the comment. I added e.preventDefault . but still the page loads refreshing :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my finalized complete code after following your all suggestions. But it is still refreshing when getting results. Let's see if I have made any further error in the code. Thanks for your all helps.

UPDATE! - All these HTML and PHP scripts resides in the same file called 23.php

```html
<!--
 Submit form without refreshing
-->

<html>
<head>
 <title>My first PHP page</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {            
      $("#btn").click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var myname = $("#name").val();
          var myage = $("#age").val();
          yourData ='myname='+myname+'&myage='+myage;
              $.ajax({
                 type:'POST',
                 data:yourData,//Without serialized                  
                 url: '23.php',
                 success:function(data) {
                    if(data){
                        $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
                        alert('Submitted');
                    }else{
                        return false;
                     }                        
                  };
               });                    
         });            
           
      });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="testform"> <!-- $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] array -->
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
   Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn"/>
  </form>

 
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) { //was the form submitted?

        echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
    }
?>
```